# Find word in string and replace it

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string [XML], I want to find tags that contain a word and replace that tag with another name.

I have tried using this, with no success:

```
var regex = new Regex(@"\bKeyValueOfstringOutcome\b", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
string result = regex.Replace(xml.Document.ToString(), "");
```

This is my XML:

```
<Response>
  <Outcome>
    <KeyValueOfstringOutcomeTest1>
      <Key>Icon</Key>
      <Value>
        <DataType>System.String</DataType>
        <Field>Icon</Field>
        <Value>O</Value>
      </Value>
    </KeyValueOfstringOutcomeTest1>
    <KeyValueOfstringOutcomeTest2>
      <Key>IconDescription</Key>
      <Value>
        <DataType>System.String</DataType>
        <Field>IconDescription</Field>
        <Value>Old</Value>
      </Value>
    </KeyValueOfstringOutcomeTest2>
    <KeyValueOfstringOutcomeTest3>
      <Key>IconLongDescription</Key>
      <Value>
        <DataType>System.String</DataType>
        <Field>IconLongDescription</Field>
        <Value>Older</Value>
      </Value>
    </KeyValueOfstringOutcomeTest3>
  </Outcome>
</Response>
```

I need to find the nodes that contain KeyValueOfstringOutcome, and replace KeyValueOfstringOutcomeTest1, KeyValueOfstringOutcomeTest2, KeyValueOfstringOutcomeTest3 with KeyValueOfstringOutcome.

Comment: That node namings are chosen really bad. You really should rename the wrapper for your `key-value` paired nodes.

Comment: what exactly is your problem? the matching of the `KeyValueOfstringOutcomeTest1, KeyValueOfstringOutcomeTest2, KeyValueOfstringOutcomeTest3` strings?

Comment: To be honest I don't quite get what you're trying to do. I assume you want to rename the Nodes?

Comment: To be honest, doing string replacement to fix XML sounds like a really bad solution, but here goes: `Regex.Replace(xml, "(</?KeyValueOfstringOutcome)[^>]+>", ma => ma.Groups[1].Value + ">")`

Answer (score 0):

Try this if it help.

```
string result = Regex.Replace(xml.Document.ToString(), "[a-zA-Z0-9]*KeyValueOfstringOutcome[a-zA-Z0-9]*","KeyValueOfstringOutcome");
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly that you want to get rid of `Test1`, `Test2` and so on.
I would suggest to use this [Replace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Text_RegularExpressions_Regex_Replace_System_String_System_String_System_String_) method.

```
string replacedXML = Regex.Replace(xml.Document.ToString(),
                                   @"KeyValueOfstringOutcomeTest\d+",
                                    "KeyValueOfstringOutcome");
```

`\d+` will match 1 or more occurences of a digit behind your keyword

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn´t use `REGEX` to match and change the name of the nodes.
If you ever update your file or namings it´s going to crash or change some other node which contains the buzzword, too.

So I would create a loop through each `childnode` at the lvl/hierarchy you want to change and then grap it and rename it.

```
foreach (XmlNode node in doc.ChildNodes)
{        
    // [2] should be the the deepth of childenotes named `KeyValueOfstringOutcomeTestX`
    node.ChildNode[2].Name = "YOUR NEW NAME TO THIS NODE";  
}
doc.Save();  // Change renamed nodes to the document.
```

Answer (score 0):

Use xml linq :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication107
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);
            List<XElement> keyValueOfstringOutcomeTests = doc.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName.StartsWith("KeyValueOfstringOutcomeTest")).ToList();
            foreach (XElement keyValueOfstringOutcomeTest in keyValueOfstringOutcomeTests)
            {
                keyValueOfstringOutcomeTest.ReplaceWith(new XElement("KeyValueOfstringOutcomeTest", keyValueOfstringOutcomeTest.Elements()));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I've done to accomplish this.

```
var match = Regex.Match(xml.Document.ToString(), @"KeyValueOfstringOutcome.*>");
                if (match.Success)
                {
                    var replacedText = Regex.Replace(xml.Document.ToString(), @"KeyValueOfstringOutcome.*>", "KeyValueOfstringOutcome>");
                }
```